# How to get line in a file partially by C++

Tags: c++, vector, fstream, stdvector, getline

I want to read data in an input file partially. For example, input file is 1GB, I want to read only 100MB each time, then store in a vector. How can I continue reading the next line after the first loop? As you can see in my code below, after the first loop of i, maybe the vector v stored 1000 lines from the input file. I'm not sure if the next loop of i, the command while(std::getline(infile, line)) will continue to read from line 1001 from the input file or not? If not, how can I modify my code to get lines from the input in several groups (1~1000), (1001~2000), (2001~3000)... then store in vector v?

```
#define FILESIZE  1000000000            // size of the file on disk
#define TOTAL_MEM 100000            // max items the memory buffer can hold

void ExternalSort(std::string infilepath, std::string outfilepath)
{    
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    int runs_count;
    std::ifstream infile;
    if(!infile.is_open())
    {   
        std::cout << "Unable to open file\n";           
    }
    infile.open(infilepath, std::ifstream::in);

    if(FILESIZE  % TOTAL_MEM > 0)
            runs_count = FILESIZE/TOTAL_MEM + 1;        
        else
            runs_count = FILESIZE/TOTAL_MEM;

        // Iterate through the elements in the file
        for(i = 0; i < runs_count; i++)
        {
            // Step 1: Read M-element chunk at a time from the file
            for (j = 0; j < (TOTAL_MEM < FILESIZE ? TOTAL_MEM : FILESIZE); j++)
            {
                while(std::getline(infile, line))
                {
                    // If line is empty, ignore it
                    if(line.empty())
                        continue;
                    new_line = line + "\n";
                    // Line contains string of length > 0 then save it in vector
                    if(new_line.size() > 0)
                        v.push_back(new_line);
                }   
            }
            // Step 2: Sort M elements
            sort(v.begin(), v.end());       //sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare); 

            // Step 3: Create temporary files and write sorted data into those files.
            std::ofstream tf;
            tf.open(tfile + ToString(i) + ".txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app); 
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string> output_iterator(tf, "\n");
            std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), output_iterator);
            v.clear();
            //for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
            //  tf << *it << "\n";

            tf.close();
        }   
        infile.close();
```

Comment: Not clear what the problem is - you are not closing infile inside the loop so any subsequent reads will continue from the last position.

Comment: Just fyi, `if(new_line.size() > 0)` - is pointless. You've already determined its not going to be empty from the prior two lines. In fact, the prior line *guarantees* `new_line.size() > 0` will always be true. And as cup pointed out, the `while(std::getline(infile, line))` loop will consume the entire input file whether you like it or not. Your statement, *"after the first loop of i, maybe the vector v stored 1000 lines from the input file."* is false. There is no other condition to break that, so all the remaining for-loop hoops you're jumping through are ultimately pointless.

Comment: @cup I want to make sure the data store in output files (tf1,tf2...) get data lines from input file subsequently. e.g. tf1 gets lines from 1~1000, tf2 gets lines from 1001~2000... But I'm not sure if my current code version always store input lines from 1~1000 into all output files or it will produce as I expected.

Comment: @HectorTa *" I'm not sure if my current code version always store input lines from 1~1000"* look at the code. It consumes the entire input file, stuffing *all* non-empty lines into `v`. They're then sorted, and the entire thing is dumped into the current output file. Since you've not provided the location of definition of `v`, the other input files will either (a) be empty if v has scope inside the outer for loop, or (b) contain duplicate full data from the first pass that actually read the input file if `v` has scope outside the outer for loop.

Comment: @WhozCraig : I edited the code above, please help me check. 
File size is 200GB, RAM 8GB. So we can't read all lines from input file at once. That's why I need to divide input data to several parts and store in multiple output files. So, my code can only get duplicate data to all output files? How can I make output files store data without duplicate? e.g. output1 stores input lines 1~1000, output2 stores lines 1001~2000 from input file. 
Don't care about the command while(std::getline(infile, line)), maybe we need to use another command for this task. But I don't know how.

Comment: Why not just scale it down, then you can check easily - reduce 1000 to 5 and stop after 3 files.  It is quite easy to check that the 3 files contain the 15 lines of the parent file.  Once you get that working, scale it up.

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t have the patience to check the whole code. It was easier to write a splitter from scratch. Here are some observations, anyhow:

> ```
>   std::ifstream infile;
>   if (!infile.is_open())
>   {
>     std::cout << "Unable to open file\n";
>   }
>   infile.open(infilepath, std::ifstream::in);
> ```

You will always get the message since you check **before** opening the file. One correct way to open a file is:

```
  std::ifstream infile(infilepath);
  if (!infile)
    throw "could not open the input file";
```

> ```
> if (infile.peek() == std::ifstream::traits_type::eof())
> ```

This will be true, for instance, **even for nonexistent files**. The algorithm should work for empty files, too.

> ```
> if(FILESIZE  % TOTAL_MEM > 0)
>             runs_count = FILESIZE/TOTAL_MEM + 1;        
>         else
>             runs_count = FILESIZE/TOTAL_MEM;
> ```

Why do you need the number of resulting files **before** generate them? You will never be able to calculate it correctly since it depends on how long lines are (you cannot read half of line just to fit it into `TOTAL_MEM`). You should read from input file at most `TOTAL_MEM` bytes (but a line, at least), sort & save and then continue from where you left (see the loop in `execute`, below).

> How can I continue reading the next line after the first loop?

If you **do not close** the input stream, the next read will continue from exactly where you left.

**A solution**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

std::vector<std::string> split_file(const char* fn, std::size_t mem); // see the implementation below

int main()
{
  const std::size_t max_mem = 8;
  auto r = split_file("input.txt", max_mem);

  std::cout << "generated files:" << std::endl;
  for (const auto& fn : r)
    std::cout << fn << std::endl;
 }

class split_file_t
{
public:
  split_file_t(std::istream& is, std::size_t mem) :is_{ is }, mem_{ mem }
  {
    // nop
  }

  std::vector<std::string> execute()
  {
    while (make_file())
      ;
    return std::move(ofiles_);
  }

protected:
  std::istream& is_;
  std::size_t mem_;
  std::vector<std::string> ofiles_;

  static std::string make_temp_file()
  {

    std::string fn(512, 0);
    tmpnam_s(&fn.front(), fn.size()); // this might be system dependent
    std::ofstream os(fn);
    os.close();
    return fn;
  }

  bool make_file()
  {
    using namespace std;

    // read lines
    vector<string> lines;
    {
      streamsize max_gpos = is_.tellg() + streamsize(mem_);
      string line;
      while (is_.tellg() < max_gpos && getline(is_, line))
        lines.push_back(line);
    }

    //
    if (lines.empty())
      return false;

    // sort lines
    sort(lines.begin(), lines.end());

    // save lines
    {
      string ofile = make_temp_file();
      ofstream os{ ofile };
      if (!os)
        throw "could not open output file";
      copy(lines.begin(), lines.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(os, "\n"));
      ofiles_.push_back(ofile);
    }

    //
    return bool(is_);
  }
};

std::vector<std::string> split_file(const char* fn, std::size_t mem)
{
  using namespace std;

  ifstream is{ fn };
  if (!is)
    return vector<string>();

  return split_file_t{ is, mem }.execute();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But what's #include <filesystem>? The compiler showed error at that line. Even after I deleted it, there was another error at tmpnam_s(&fn.front(), fn.size());

Comment: You can remove it. I left it by accident.

Comment: [`tmpnam_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/tmpnam) might be system dependent. You should check your user manual for an equivalent function. Try `tmpnam`.